# How can I parse hundreds of *.lyr files for their Definition Queries?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, definition-query, layer-file

I have ~600 lyr files that reference a table on an SDE database that has about 20,000,000 records.  Some of these *lyr files have an incorrect definition query applied or is missing the query entirely.

I think I'm looking for a way to create a table with the Lyr file name and it's definition query, but I'm not sure if that's something I can do in python or model builder.  Can anyone pt me in the right direction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`arcpy.mapping`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s300000032000000) module makes it pretty easy if you're comfortable doing a little Python coding.  Here's the basic outline:

At the beginning of your Python script, get the list of `.lyr` files (using [`glob.glob("*.lyr")`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html), for example).

Then for each file, call [`arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(filename)`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/ListLayers/00s30000002n000000/), passing it the filename of your `.lyr` file.  This returns a list of [`Layer`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Layer/00s300000008000000/) objects.

Each of these [`Layer`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Layer/00s300000008000000/) objects has a `definitionQuery` property that you could print or write to a file.

I imagine the code would be something like this (though I haven't actually tried to run this):

```
import glob
import arcpy
import arcpy.mapping
filenames = glob.glob("C:\\path\\to\\layer\\files\\*.lyr");
for filename in filenames:
    layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(filename)
    for layer in layers:
        print filename + ',' + layer.longName + ',' + layer.definitionQuery
```

And you should get output like this:

```
C:\path\to\layer\files\foo.lyr,Some Layer Name,WHERE foo='xyz'
C:\path\to\layer\files\var.lyr,Another Layer Name,WHERE foo='abc'
```

Answer (score 4):

This function (`inventory_layers_and_mxds`) will create a new table and populate it with definition queries

```
import os

import arcpy

def inventory_layers_and_mxds(out_table, folder_to_inventory, mxds=True, lyrs=True):
    # Set up inventory table
    print [os.path.dirname(out_table),
           os.path.basename(out_table)]
    arcpy.management.CreateTable(os.path.dirname(out_table),
                                 os.path.basename(out_table))
    arcpy.management.AddField(out_table, "mapdocument", "TEXT",
                              field_length=320)
    arcpy.management.AddField(out_table, "layername", "TEXT",
                              field_length=128)
    arcpy.management.AddField(out_table, "definitionquery", "TEXT",
                              field_length=320)

    # open cursor, loop over directory looking for MXDs
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(out_table,
                               ["mapdocument",
                                "layername",
                                "definitionquery"]) as inv_cursor:
        # Spider through folder
        for foldername, subdirectories, files in os.walk(folder_to_inventory):
            for filename in files:
                file_path = os.path.join(foldername, filename)
                item = None
                # Is file an MXD and are we looking at map docs?
                if os.path.splitext(filename)[1].lower() == ".mxd" and mxds:
                    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(file_path)
                    item = mxd 
                # Is file a LYR and are we looking at layers?
                if os.path.splitext(filename)[1].lower() == ".lyr" and lyrs:
                    lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer(file_path)
                    item = lyr
                if item is not None:
                    # Now loop over layers
                    for layer in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(item):
                        # Only insert row if it does a definition query
                        # (ignore group layers etc)
                        if layer.supports("DEFINITIONQUERY"):
                            inv_cursor.insertRow([file_path, layer.longName,
                                                  layer.definitionQuery])
```

Answer (score 2):

With the ArcPy Mapping module you can read or write a Layers definitionQuery. Here is a blog post.
[Working with a Definition Query, ArcPy and Python](http://kesslergis.blogspot.com/2012/12/working-with-definition-query-arcpy-and.html)